# Cartographer on multi robots simulation not running

Tags: simulation, gazebo, mapping, ros2

I am currently trying to set up a ROS2 foxy multi robots simulation.
However I'm facing an issue, the first instance of cartographer that I launch works. But if I try to launch any more instance, they will not provide anything. I can see that its subscribing to the right topics, but it's not publishing anything on the topics (like submap or tf). And I don't have any error message except occupancy grid complaining of empty submaps.

This is the main launch file, creating all the robots :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

-- coding: utf-8 --
import sys
import os
import random
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory, get_package_prefix
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, SetEnvironmentVariable
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, TextSubstitution, Command
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.descriptions import ParameterValue
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import ThisLaunchFileDir
import os.path

spawn_points = [[20.0, -38.0, 0.0], [68.0, -22.0, 0.0], [-14.0, 36.0, 0.0], [70.0, 23.0, 0.0],[58.0, -61.0, 0.0],[40.0, 17.0, 0.0],[-20.0, -35.0, 0.0],[33.0, 44.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

def gen_robot_list(number_of_robots):

robots = []

for i in range(number_of_robots):
    robot_name = "tb3_"+str(i)
    x_pos = float(i)
    pkg_bc_ros2 = get_package_share_directory('bc_ros2')

    full_path = os.path.join(pkg_bc_ros2, 'robot/', 'turtlebot3_waffle'+str(i)+'.sdf')
    check_file = os.path.isfile(full_path)
    print("Checking if file exists: "+str(check_file)+" "+full_path)
    #if(check_file == False):
    print("Creating new urdf file for robot "+robot_name)
    os.system("cp "+pkg_bc_ros2+"/robot/turtlebot3_waffleX.sdf "+full_path)
    os.system("sed -i 's/tb3_0/"+robot_name+"/g' "+full_path)
    spawn = spawn_points[random.randint(0,spawn_points.__len__()-1)]
    spawn_points.remove(spawn)
    robots.append({'name': robot_name, 'x_pose': spawn[0], 'y_pose':spawn[1], 'z_pose': spawn[2], 'path':full_path})


return robots 
def generate_launch_description():

pkg_turtlebot_description = get_package_share_directory('turtlebot3_description')
urdf = os.path.join(pkg_turtlebot_description, 'urdf/', 'turtlebot3_waffle.urdf')

pkg_box_bot_description = get_package_share_directory('box_bot_description')

#assert os.path.exists(urdf), "Thebox_bot.urdf doesnt exist in "+str(urdf)

# Names and poses of the robots
robots = gen_robot_list(2)



# We create the list of spawn robots commands and the robot state publisher
spawn_robots_cmds = []
for robot in robots:
    #spawn_robots_cmds.append(os.environ['ROBOT_NAME'] = robot['name'])
    spawn_robots_cmds.append(
        SetEnvironmentVariable(
            name="ROBOT_NAME",
            value=robot['name']
        )
    )
    spawn_robots_cmds.append(
        
        Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': True},
                    {'robot_description': ParameterValue(
                        Command(['xacro ', str(urdf)]), value_type=str),
                    'publish_frequency': 50.0, 'frame_prefix':str(robot['name']+"/")

            }],
            arguments=[urdf],
            
            node_namespace=robot['name'],
            #remappings = [("/joint_states",robot['name']+"/joint_states"),("/tf", robot['name'] + "/tf"),("/tf_static", robot['name'] + "/tf_static")],
        )
    )
    spawn_robots_cmds.append(
        Node(
            package='gazebo_ros',
            executable='spawn_entity.py',
            name='spawn_entity_' + robot['name'],
            output='screen',
            node_namespace=robot['name'],
            arguments=['-entity', robot['name'], '-x', str(robot['x_pose']), '-y', str(robot['y_pose']), '-z', str(robot['z_pose']), '-file', str(robot['path'])],
        )
     )
    
    spawn_robots_cmds.append(
        Node(
            package='bc_ros2',
            executable='lidar_limiter',
            name='lidar_limiter' + robot['name'],
            output='screen',
            node_namespace=robot['name'],
            arguments=['robot_name', robot['name']],
        )
     )
    spawn_robots_cmds.append(
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(), '/cartographer.launch.py']),
        launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items(),
    ),)


# Create the launch description and populate
ld = LaunchDescription()

for spawn_robot_cmd in spawn_robots_cmds:
    ld.add_action(spawn_robot_cmd)

return ld`
```

And this is cartographer.launch.py

```
# Copyright 2019 Open Source Robotics Foundation, Inc.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
Author: Darby Lim
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import ThisLaunchFileDir
import os.path

def generate_launch_description():
use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='false')
turtlebot3_cartographer_prefix = get_package_share_directory('bc_ros2')
cartographer_config_dir = LaunchConfiguration('cartographer_config_dir', default=os.path.join(
turtlebot3_cartographer_prefix, 'config'))
#configuration_basename = LaunchConfiguration('configuration_basename',
#default='cartographer.lua')

#Checking if the robot already have a config file, if not create it
robot_name = os.environ.get('ROBOT_NAME')
print("________________________Robot name: "+robot_name)
custom_configuration_basename = LaunchConfiguration('configuration_basename',
                                             default=robot_name+'.lua')


cartographer_config_dir_str = get_package_share_directory('bc_ros2')+ '/config'
full_path = cartographer_config_dir_str+'/'+robot_name+'.lua'

check_file = os.path.isfile(full_path)
print("Checking if file exists: "+str(check_file)+" "+full_path)
print("Creating new config file for robot "+robot_name)
os.system("cp "+cartographer_config_dir_str+"/cartographer.lua "+full_path)
os.system("sed -i 's/X/"+robot_name+"/g' "+full_path)

   


resolution = LaunchConfiguration('resolution', default='0.05')
publish_period_sec = LaunchConfiguration('publish_period_sec', default='1.0')



return LaunchDescription([
    
    Node(
        package='bc_ros2',
        executable='relative_tf',
        name='relative_tf',
        output='screen',
        node_namespace=robot_name,
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,'robot_name': robot_name}],
        # remappings = [("/joint_states","/tb3_0/joint_states"),
        #               ("/tf", "/tb3_0/tf"),
        #               ("/tf_static", "/tb3_0/tf_static")],
    ),
    
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'cartographer_config_dir',
        default_value=cartographer_config_dir,
        description='Full path to config file to load'),
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'configuration_basename',
        default_value=custom_configuration_basename,
        description='Name of lua file for cartographer'),
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'use_sim_time',
        default_value='true',
        description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),

    Node(
        package='cartographer_ros',
        executable='cartographer_node',
        name='cartographer_node',
        output='screen',
        node_namespace=robot_name,
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
        remappings = [("/odom",robot_name+"/odom_relative"),("/scan",robot_name+"/scan"),],
        # remappings = [("/joint_states","/tb3_0/joint_states"),
        #               ("/tf", "/tb3_0/tf"),
        #               ("/tf_static", "/tb3_0/tf_static")],
        arguments=['-configuration_directory', cartographer_config_dir,
                   '-configuration_basename', custom_configuration_basename]),

    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'resolution',
        default_value=resolution,
        description='Resolution of a grid cell in the published occupancy grid'),

    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'publish_period_sec',
        default_value=publish_period_sec,
        description='OccupancyGrid publishing period'),

    IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(), '/occupancy_grid.launch.py']),
        launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': use_sim_time, 'resolution': resolution,
                          'publish_period_sec': publish_period_sec, 'robot_name':robot_name}.items(),
    ),

    
])
`
```

The thing to know is that it worked on monday flawlessly, but not anymore.
Thank you for your attention

Comment: What changed between when it worked and when it doesn't? Are you using version control?